# AWS single sign-on: Limit simultaneous logins

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on

In AWS single sign-on service, is it possible to limit the number of devices a user is logged on from.
Specifically, I would like the user to be logged in with one device and if trying to log in with an additional device to log him\her out from the initial device they were logged in from.

Answer (score 0):

I have provisioned SSO several times and have never came across this option.